# Can I delete Qur'an recitation audio clips from my phone?

Tags: quran, halal-haram, technology

I have many audio clips of Qur'an recitation in my phone; is it permissible to delete them?

Comment: Why should it be prohibited?

Comment: @Medi1Saif May be he is thinking it as like destroying/burning printed Quran.

Answer (score 4):

Electronic copies of the Quran doesn't come under the same ruling as mushafs. Because writing Quran on the mobile phone or computers is not like writing it in a Mushaf. Electronic texts are not permanent, they appear when you open the app or the file containing the Quran and disappear when you close it. The specific instructions prescribed for destroying a mushaf don't apply to them.

**So, it is permissible to delete them.**